# Calculating the "Belvedere Hull" of a Simple Planar Polygon

Tags: reference-request, computational-geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons

As an informal motivation the problem, imagine a tower with polygonal footprint, that is located in a beautiful landscape, the "Belvedere Hull" is then related to the directions, in which one would have a view unobstructed by the tower (it is assumed that the tower has roof, so it is not possible to stand on top of it).

> **Problem:**
>   given a simple, planar polygon, calculate the boundary of the union of all half-lines that do not contain inner points of the polygon, i.e. the "Belvedere Hull".

This problem seems to be related to the visibility from a point inside the polygon, or to the art gallery problem, so I would like to know if this problem has already been considered or, how to tackle it.

Generalizations can easily be envisaged, by either going to higher-dimensional spaces and/or, by replacing the polygon by other, not necessarily connected point-sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your concept is called
a *weakly externally visible* polygon in the literature.

---

[image: WeaklyVisible]

---

The above figure is from the chapter,
"Visibility in the Plane" by Asano, Ghosh, Shermer, in
*The Handbook of Computational Geometry*.
Likely Ghosh's book is the best source:

> Ghosh, Subir Kumar. 
>   *Visibility algorithms in the plane*. (Vol.2). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2007.

The concept is studied extensively in the context of 3D graphics, e.g.,

> Wang, Caoan, and Binhai Zhu. "Three dimensional weak visibility: Complexity and applications." *Computing and Combinatorics*. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 1995. 51-60.

Comment: thanks for providing the name of my problem and for the pointers to the literature.

Comment: @ManfredWeis: I am aware that I didn't directly answer your question about the *weakly visible hull*. It may be in those references, either explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: that is often the hard part, namely to get to know the name of a problem as the magic word that grants access to further information; so your answer is perfectly ok for me.